# Get list of names of running processes in python

Tags: python, process, tuples, psutil

I need to get list of names of running processes in python. I m doing this by `psutil.process_iter` in a `for` loop. But i need faster way to check if process is running. Also if it would be possible, rather then a `list` I would appreciate a `tuple`. Thanks for any response.

Comment: are you willing have the name of process that are running on you OS??

Comment: I didn't really understand your comment.. but I m running windows (10) and I need THE FASTEST way to check if process `somename.exe` is currently running or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WMI, there is an example in Python using the wmi module:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
    print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

Comment: I tried and it is probably the slowest thing I have ever seen :)

Comment: probably you have to work with another programming language, you can't have better execution time performance in python